# Column Chart in Second Panel in Amcharts

Tags: amcharts

Am trying to change the display type of graph from second panel onward, but even after specifying the change - "type" : "column" the second chart continues to be displayed as line chart.

https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/stock-chart-displaying-data-different-data-sets-separate-panels/

Am I missing some setting here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For compared data sets, you have to set the corresponding `compareGraph*` setting for the setting to work. In this case you want to set `compareGraphType` to `"column"`. If you want the columns filled, set `compareGraphFillAlphas` to 1. You can see all the available properties in the [stockGraph documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/StockGraph).

Here's an updated version of the above demo: http://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/9f58168c0164f51c0f4549780143d37e?editors=0010